# sql server equivalent oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracleclient

what should i use to connect an oracle database with a c# program,
I mean for sqlClient there is sql server , and what is the best one for oracleClient, thanx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has its own .Net driver and ODP Components.

Use ODAC from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html